# How can I run Corel Draw?

Tags: wine

I have purchased Corel Draw and I am required to use it for school.  Can I install this program on my Ubuntu system or is my Windows machine the only option here? I do have Inkscape and love it but I have a professor that requires Corel Draw in class.

As well, there are other programs that I will be required to use for school in the future, if I cannot use Corel Draw with Ubuntu, then is it safe to assume that I won't be able to use any of the others with my Ubuntu system if a professor insists on one in particular?  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 6):

You can not run it natively. If you want to stick with Ubuntu and not depend on Windows Inkscape would be the best alternative. If you must use Corel Draw ...

- Dual booting is always an option.
- The best method from within Ubuntu would be to install VirtualBox, install Windows inside a VirtualBox and install Corel Draw inside Windows. [There is a very good and very lenghty tutorial on how to do this on ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=900020). This would be my advice since you can then also install all kinds of other software you might need that is Windows only.
- Wine most times is a viable option but for Corel Draw it seems to be a gamble. [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=440) shows a lot of garbage ratings and 1 platinum. Without some knowledge on how Wine works and how you can troubleshoot problems adds an extra difficulty. Plus if you want to use extra other software you would face that problem again.